# Deploying WAR with CXF in Glassfish V3

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, cxf, glassfish-3

I'm trying to deploy a WAR in GF V3 that has CXF as a dependency and I get the following exception:

```
[#|2011-02-08T07:34:15.736-0800|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080-(2);|StandardWrapperValve[MyServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet MyServlet threw exception
com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportPipeFactory: Provider com.sun.enterprise.jbi.serviceengine.bridge.transport.JBITransportPipeFactory is specified in bundle://254.0:0/META-INF/services/com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportPipeFactory but not found
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceFinder.fail(ServiceFinder.java:241)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceFinder.access$100(ServiceFinder.java:141)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceFinder$LazyIterator.next(ServiceFinder.java:376)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportTubeFactory.create(TransportTubeFactory.java:129)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.<init>(DeferredTransportPipe.java:82)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.ClientTubeAssemblerContext.createTransportTube(ClientTubeAssemblerContext.java:311)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.TransportTubeFactory.createTube(TransportTubeFactory.java:62)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.createTube(TubeCreator.java:77)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:121)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:224)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:201)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:174)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:81)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:602)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:344)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:326)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:308)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:99)
        at com.mycompany.myapp.webserviceclient.SomeWebserviceService.getSomeWebservicePort(SomeWebserviceService.java:58)
```

This sorta indicates to me that there is a bundle in my WAR\lib directory that is causing problems, but when I expand the WAR and do a search on META-INF\services I do not find anything that is close what is outlined in the exception.

I originally had CXF and it's transitive dependencies in the war\lib dir, but I've since removed that and still encounter the same error.

Nothing useful comes up when searching google and I'm at a loss here.

Does anyone know what might be going on here?

**EDIT #1**

Another symptom of this is that the tester pages for deployed web services will not work properly.

Comment: The irony in this is that everyone (including me) complains about Axis, but this app worked perfectly with Axis :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my glassfish3.1. Below is a stack trace

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportPipeFactory: Provider com.sun.enterprise.jbi.serviceengine.bridge.transport.JBITransportPipeFactory is specified in bundle://96.0:0/META-INF/services/com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportPipeFactory but not found
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceFinder.fail(ServiceFinder.java:245)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceFinder.access$100(ServiceFinder.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceFinder$LazyIterator.next(ServiceFinder.java:380)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportTubeFactory.create(TransportTubeFactory.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.<init>(DeferredTransportPipe.java:86)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.ClientTubeAssemblerContext.createTransportTube(ClientTubeAssemblerContext.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.TransportTubeFactory.createTube(TransportTubeFactory.java:67)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.createTube(TubeCreator.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:228)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:205)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:608)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:330)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:312)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.initializePort(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:563)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doGet(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:114)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletAdapter.java:1002)
    ... 20 more
```

The problem was traced to the conflicting mappings for "com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportPipeFactory" inside two different modules.

```
prompt> grep -rl com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportPipeFactory /usr/local/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/modules*

modules/webservices-osgi.jar
modules/sun-javaee-engine.jar

prompt> grep -rl com.sun.enterprise.jbi.serviceengine.bridge.transport.JBITransportPipeFactory /usr/local/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/modules/*
modules/sun-javaee-engine.jar
```

Clearly, the required file was sitting in the wrong jar "sun-javaee-engine.jar".

Above, "sun-javaee-engine.jar" is loaded by the "Java EE Service Engine Module". Once I removed the module (using glassfish update tool) everything started working fine.

**EDIT #1:**
Here is how to remove the module using the update tool on the Unix command line:

```
sudo ./pkg uninstall sun-javaee-engine
```